# AngularJS remove URL parameter with HTML5Mode = false

Tags: angularjs

I type url and press enter http://myservertest.com?auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

This one will call a service with auth param to authenticate, after authorization is successful, I want my url should be like this http://myservertest.com/mainpage without refresh app controller again.

I tried windows.location = "/" then it will refresh the page.

How can I do without refresh APP Controller ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: are you using angular routing?

Comment: yes, i am using angular routing with html5mode false so the way on $location.search() does not work

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles about this again after I stumbled about this after 7 years:

Usually you solve it by using $location:

```
$location.url('<url>');
$location.replace();
```

**But...** default html5Mode this will not replace window.location.search query parameters like

`http://localhost/path?auth=xxx&andso=on`

Without html5Mode (enabled:false by default) you need to **care about pushState yourself before** the AngularJs application runs:

Solution is to **use...**

`window.history.replaceState(null, window.name, window.location.origin + window.location.path + window.location.hash)`

(an example replacing the currently shown location url without parameters)

**.. in an angular.provider() or angular.config():**

In a provider when offering a reusable service:

```
angular.module('app').provider('AuthService', [
 'someConfig', 
 function(someConfig){
  
  if (someConfigObject.doItBeforeStartup) {
    // ... check for parameter in window.location.search or whatever
   
    window.history.replaceState(null, window.name, window.origin + window.path + window.hash)
  }

  this.readQuery = function(cfg){./* you can do it also here and call it in config*/..}

  this.$get = ...


}]);
```

and/or in an config when using providers:

```
angular.module('app').config([
  'AuthServiceProvider',
  'someConfig',
  function (AuthServiceProvider, someConfig) {

    window.history.replaceState(.....)
    // or in
    // AuthServiceProvider.readQuery(...)
    
}]);
```